# no required module provides package fyne.io/fyne/app: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory on intel mac

Tags: go, user-interface, installation, fyne

I'm getting this error when trying 'go build'

**no required module provides package fyne.io/fyne/app: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
test.go:5:5: no required module provides package fyne.io/fyne/widget: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'**

But i'm installed fyne.io/fyne and i don't know why i have this mistake. I tried to reinstall Go but it's didn't help

[image]

Comment: The error says _"go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'"_. It appears you have not created a module, see [Getting Started](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started) or [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code).

Comment: I'm beginner in developing and i don't know many things. But you're right. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Go 1.16 modules are required so you need to run `go mod init <project name>`.
Note also that for Fyne you should use the v2 imports now, which are `”fyne.io/fyne/v2”`. And you should install the `fyne` tool from `fyne.io/fyne/v2/cmd/fyne`.